# My onClose or onOpen prop functionality is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, components, react-props

I am trying to change and wrap another component "Modal" to my conversations panel.
My last component's name was SlidingPanel which had a different functionality. **I am trying to pass my onClickOutside, open and or onCloseClick prop to the modal so that when clicking the close button or clicking outside the modal, the modal closes and opens again**. Somehow I pass the props and they are not working.

I have a ChatModuleContainer which returns my ChatModule component:

```
    const onOpenChat = () => {
        if (props.onOpenChatModal) props.onOpenChatModal();
    };

return (
    <ChatModule
            fetching={!ready}
            notifications={notifications}
            unreadMessages={unreadMessages}
            panelTitle={panelTitle}
            panelTitleIcon={MODAL_TITLE_ICON}
            emptyMessage={emptyMessage}
            top={panelTop}
            bottom={panelBottom}
            chatButtonTop={chatButtonTop}
            chatButtonBottom={chatButtonBottom}
            floatingButtonRef={floatingButtonRef}
            onNavigateToItem={onNavigateToItem}
            onOpenChat={onOpenChat}
            {...props}
        />
);
```

Inside my ChatModule component I return my chatting float button that opens my ChatNotificationsPanel component:

```
    const closePanelClicked = (e) => {
        closeChatNotificationsPanel();
    };

return (
        <div
            className={chatNotificationsPanelClassName}
            style={chatNotificationsPanelContainerStyle}
        >
            {!showCloseButton && renderFloatingChatButton()}

            <ChatNotificationsPanel
                fetching={fetching}
                open={chatNotificationsPanelOpen}
                isMobile={isMobileWidth}
                notifications={notifications}
                panelTitle={panelTitle}
                panelTitleIcon={panelTitleIcon}
                emptyMessage={emptyMessage}
                onNavigateToItem={notificationClicked}
                onCloseClick={closePanelClicked}
                onClickOutside={closePanelClicked}
                width={chatNotificationsPanelWidth}
            />

            {showCloseButton && renderFloatingButtons()}
        </div>
    );
```

in my ChatNotificationsPanel is where I want to change my SlidingPanel component to my Modal component.

This is how it looks now:

```
return (
            <SlidingPanel
                width={width}
                open={open}
                top={top}
                bottom={bottom}
                onClickOutside={onClickOutside}
                side="right"
            >
                <div className={listClassName}>
                    <CuaddsWindow
                        title={panelTitle}
                        icon={panelTitleIcon}
                        showCloseButton={true}
                        onClose={onCloseClick}
                        className={usesHelpCenter ? "chatContainerStyle" : "oldChatStyle"}
                        classNameToAdd={"titleStyle"}
                        headerBackgroundColor={usesHelpCenter ? "#474747" : ""}
                    ></CuaddsWindow>

                    {this.renderNotificationsList()}
                </div>
            </SlidingPanel>
        );
```

I am trying to Change SlidingPanel to Modal, like this:

```
    return (
            <Modal
                onClickOutside={onClickOutside}
                style={{ width: width, top: top, bottom: bottom }}
                onClick={open}
            >
                <div className={listClassName}>
                    <Window
                        title={panelTitle}
                        icon={panelTitleIcon}
                        showCloseButton={true}
                        onClose={onCloseClick}
                        className={usesHelpCenter ? "chatContainerStyle" : "oldChatStyle"}
                        classNameToAdd={"titleStyle"}
                        headerBackgroundColor={usesHelpCenter ? "#474747" : ""}
                    ></Window>

                    {this.renderNotificationsList()}
                </div>
            </Modal>
        );
```

But it is not working, Can anyone help me to see what I am doing wrong? and how should I fix this?

Comment: I think you have bloated your question a little.  What isn't actually working and I don't know if its worth display `SlidingPanel` if you're not going to be using it anymore.  Kinda hard to follow at least for me.

Comment: Opening and closing the modal doesnt work on my Modal component while it works on the SlidingPanel, So I am trying to see why my  onClickOutside={onClickOutside} or open modal are not functioning correctly.